# JQuery traverse table

Tags: jquery

How to traverse table in JQuery?

Code is as follows,

```
<table id="tblData">
  <tr id="tr_1">
     <td><input type="text" id="txtData1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr_4">
     <td><input type="text" id="txtData4" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr_10">
     <td><input type="text" id="txtData10" /></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

How to get html of each row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#tblData tr').each(function() {
    alert($(this).find('input').val()); // `this` is TR DOM element
});
```