# Jquery traversing table and replace its contents

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-traversing

I have this table and I have to traverse using `Jquery`:

```
<table id="answer">
<thead>
  <tr class="grdheader">
    <td><input type="checkbox" style="border:0px"id="a1chkAll"></td>
    <td>Free Text</td>
    <td>Weighting</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr id="tdata">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="440" id="achk" checked="checked"></td>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tdata">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="440" id="achk" checked="checked"></td>
    <td>PQR</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tdata">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="440" id="achk"></td>
    <td>LMN</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Get `Array` like this for it respective `Checkbox` is checked.

```
Array(
'<tr id="tdata">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="440" id="achk"></td>
    <td><input type="textbox" value="ABC"></td>
    <td><input type="textbox" value="2"></td>
  </tr>',
'<tr id="tdata">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="440" id="achk"></td>
    <td><input type="textbox" value="PQR"></td>
    <td><input type="textbox" value="4"></td>
  </tr>'
)
```

Comment: to start : id must be unique, input type="textbox" doesnt exists.

Comment: @RafH no its not problem i am using checkbox change event so its not problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and .child functions, you can also check a possible similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343417/jquery-traverse-table), may also help.

Comment: Perhaps you can mess around with this make shift traverse [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kJg3N/) As @RafH previously stated I would change your id's to classes for these table elements as you repeat them throughout the snippet.

Comment: but tp replace `PQR`,`ABC` to `input` box.. and i have update it with console. it works fine [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kJg3N/2/)

Comment: Hii @sebastian `input` tag not come here

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution or you can check here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasse/3xyan/)

$(function () {

```
var pids = Array();                               
$('#answer tbody').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').closest('tr').map(function(){
    var trindex = $(this).index();
    var trhtml = $('#answer tbody tr')[trindex].outerHTML;
    pids.push(trhtml);
});
```

});